# How to find the child nodes of an node of an infragistics web navigator?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview, infragistics

I need to find all the child nodes of a particular node in Infragistics tree view(WebNavigator). it is possible to get the parent() using the available property. But I need the childs. How can i access the childs of that particular node. I am using asp.net 2.0 with VB.Net. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a reference to the Node that you want to get the children.  On the server you can access them from the [Nodes](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2011.1/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.WebUI.UltraWebNavigator.v11.1~Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebNavigator.Node~Nodes.html) collection that is exposed by the Node.

If you are looking to do this in JavaScript then you can use the [getChildNodes](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2011.1/CLR4.0/?page=WebTree_Node_Object_CSOM.html) method.

Comment: i m using Vb.net . I need it in the server side.

Comment: If you have access to the Node that you want children for use the Nodes collection exposed by that Node.